# Property of polar ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A_i>0$, consider an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid $$ E:=\bigg\{x=(x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^n\bigg| \sum_i A_i x_i^2\leq 1\bigg\}$$

Then we have a polar ellipsoid $$ E':=\bigg\{ x\bigg| \sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{A_i}\leq 1\bigg\} $$

For some unit vector $u$, assume that $E$ is oneside from a hyperplane $\{x|(u,x)=1\}$. Then show that $u$ is in $E'$. How can we prove this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if all $A_i = 1$? Then $E=E'$ so $u$ is both in and not in $E'$?

Comment: I mean : Fix $u$ s.t. $|u|=1$ and $u$ is not in $E$. Assume that $\{ x|(x,u)=1\}$ is tangent to $\partial E$ or does not intersect $E$. Then $u$ is in $E'$